# Naive Bayes Ticket Classification Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, nltk, naivebayes

I currently have a CSV export from our ticketing system with two columns.

Short Description and Class.

Both are created by the agent when logging a ticket. 
eg

- Data Backup is not working,Backup
- Email change in Groups,Notes
- backup directory not found,Backup
- Email > Global - Lotus Notes,Notes

I have been asked to write a Naive Bayes program using Python that will read the short description in a CSV file and then decide how it should be classified.

I have 329 tickets that have been classified into 6 different classes.

The following is a count of each:

- Class1 60
- Class2 77
- Class3 65
- Class4 16
- Class5 18
- Class6 93

I was thinking I would have to create 6 different dictionaries (one for each class) containing all the words used in the short description, excluding the usual !"£$%^&*()<>,./?:;@'#~][{}

Then when I run the program it will tokenize the short description using nltk and compare it to all the dictionaries and whatever one has the highest matches will determine the class.

Am I going about this the right way? 
How many tickets should I be using for my sample?

The following is what I have at the moment. It basically runs through a csv file named after a class and then outputs another file with punctuation removed, all the words in lower case and in separate cells.
This data will then be used as a dictionary. 
I'm not sure if I'm going about this whole thing the right way though.

```
import csv
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer 

#Read CSV
readFile = open ('Backup.csv', 'r')
csv.readFile = csv.reader(readFile)

resultFile = open ('result.csv', 'w')
wr = csv.writer(resultFile)

#removes punctuation
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')

#for every row in file tokenize and covert to lowercase
#write tokenized words to a .csv file.
for row in csv.readFile:
    wr.writerow(tokenizer.tokenize(row[0].lower()))

readFile.close()
resultFile.close()
```

**EDIT:**
I have now started using the following which takes in the data from my two column csv file:

```
from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier
from textblob import TextBlob

with open('train.csv', 'r') as fp:
     cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(fp, format="csv")

print(cl.classify("backup"))  # "Backup"
print(cl.classify("Lotus Notes."))   #"Lotus"
etc..
```

Pretty sure I just need to get a better sample size of training and test data and then I will feed in a csv of short descriptions then update it with the class that has been calculated.

From a functionality point of view it seems to work unless I've made any glaring mistakes?

Comment: " Is the amount of tickets I have too small for training and testing?" - Yes.

Comment: What would be an adequate number?

Comment: The size of training data necessary depends on the desired quality of the output (more is better, much, much more starts to get good). But it also depends on how easy the task is – maybe there are clear keywords for each class, so the amount you have might work already (I doubt it, though). And you might be able to tweak it with clever feature selection.

Comment: Anyway, you should use a Naive Bayes Classifier (not just dictionaries), ie. `nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier`.